# Error running endpointscfg.py get_swagger_spec

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to build a project using Google Cloud Endpoints, following this guide: [Quickstart for Cloud Endpoints Frameworks on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/quickstart-frameworks-python).

I am stuck at the step of generating the OpenAPI configuration file, where I need to run this command:

**Attempt One**

```
$ lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_swagger_spec main.EchoApi --hostname your-service.appspot.com
```

I get this error:

```
-bash: lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py: Permission denied
```

**Attempt Two**

I have tried the same command with `sudo`, which returned this error:

```
sudo: lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py: command not found
```

**Attempt Three**

I have tried to `cd lib/endpoints` to run the command from the same folder as `endpointscfg.py` file:

```
$ cd lib/endpoints
$ endpointscfg.py get_swagger_spec main.EchoApi --hostname your-service.appspot.com

usage: /Users/myName/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/endpointscfg.py
       [-h] {get_client_lib, get_discovery_doc} ...
/Users/myName/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/endpointscfg.py: error: argument {get_client_lib, get_discovery_doc}: invalid choice: 'get_swagger_spec' (choose from 'get_client_lib', 'get_discovery_doc')
```

**Attempt Four**

Running it with python returns a different kind of issue:

```
$ python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_swagger_spec main.EchoApi --hostname your-service.appspot.com

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 59, in <module>
    import _endpointscfg_setup  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/Users/myName/lab/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/endpoints/_endpointscfg_setup.py", line 98, in <module>
    _SetupPaths()
  File "/Users/myName/lab/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/endpoints/_endpointscfg_setup.py", line 94, in _SetupPaths
    from google.appengine.ext import vendor
ImportError: No module named appengine.ext
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than running it directly, try running it with Python, a la:

```
python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_swagger_spec main.EchoApi --hostname your-service.appspot.com
```

Tried that and it just worked for me. I'll try and make this better (either by fixing the docs or applying some fix in the repo), but that might get you what you need in the interim.

Comment: It seems like running this brings up a different issue. I have updated my question to include details.

Comment: Were you able to successfully install the [cloud-endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/quickstart-frameworks-python#adding_the_cloud_endpoints_frameworks_library_to_the_sample_api) library?

Comment: Yes. I have tried deleting `lib` and installing cloud-endpoints library once more. Then I tried running `python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py ...`. Same error. Here is the message to confirm my cloud-endpoints installation.

*Successfully installed cachetools dogpile.cache enum34-1.1.6 future-0.15.2 google-apitools google-endpoints google-endpoints-api-management httplib2-0.9.2 oauth2client-3.0.0 ply-3.8 pyasn1-0.1.9 pyasn1-modules-0.0.8 pycrypto pyjwkest pylru requests rsa-3.4.2 setuptools-1.1.6 six-1.4.1 strict-rfc3339 urllib3*

Comment: My apologies. I had forgotten to include the last line on the traceback: `ImportError: No module named appengine.ext`. Upon checking /google, I could not find the appengine module.

Comment: Ah, okay. Do you have the App Engine Python SDK installed?

Comment: I have both the the App Engine Python SDK (GoogleAppEngineLauncher) and the Google Cloud SDK installed from this page: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/download

Comment: just checking to see if you might have any idea as to why this is happening.

Comment: I mean, this seems like a generic Python packaging issue, but I can't reproduce what's happening to you. What version of python are you on? Do you know what version of google-endpoints is being installed? (It'll be in the first couple of lines from the `pip install` command, i.e. `Downloading google-endpoints-2.0.0b3.tar.gz (106kB): 106kB downloaded`.)

Comment: I am running on `Python 2.7.10` and downloaded `google-endpoints-2.0.0b3.tar.gz`. An interesting things happened while I was trying to install google-endpoints again — I am getting a `RuntimeError: autoconf error`. I created a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39968590/runtimeerror-autoconf-error-while-installing-google-endpoints

Comment: @haopei did you manage to resolve the issue, i am having problems with it for the past few days?

Comment: @haopei, resolved the issue, turns out google lib was a wrong one, i think this one was pulled by BeautifulSoup4. Once i created and activated a new virtualenv, endpointscfg.py worked like a charm.

Comment: @haopei I am getting this error "No module named google.appengine.ext". Can you tell me how do you solved this? Thanks

Comment: I hadn't solve the overall issue, although this accepted answer resolved the step at which I was stuck at the time. It seems like this step has further complications today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788056/get-importerror-no-module-named-control-when-following-google-cloud-endpoint-tu
@WillHayworth, would you know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and tried the same things. What worked for me was:

```
chmod +x lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py
```

Then running the command again.