# RuntimeError: autoconf error, while installing google-endpoints

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, gcloud

I am following this Cloud Endpoints quickstart guide, but I am having trouble installing google-endpoints using this command:

```
$  pip install -t lib google-endpoints --extra-index-url=https://gapi-pypi.appspot.com/admin/nurpc-dev --ignore-installed
```

The returned traceback is this:

```
pip install -t lib google-endpoints --extra-index-url=https://gapi-pypi.appspot.com/admin/nurpc-dev --ignore-installed
Collecting google-endpoints
  Using cached google-endpoints-2.0.0b3.tar.gz
Collecting google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1 (from google-endpoints)
  Using cached google-endpoints-api-management-1.0.0b2.tar.gz
Collecting cachetools<2,>=1.0.0 (from google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached cachetools-1.1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting dogpile.cache<0.7,>=0.6.1 (from google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached dogpile.cache-0.6.2.tar.gz
Collecting enum34<2,>=1.1.6 (from google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting google-apitools<0.5,>=0.4.15 (from google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached google_apitools-0.4.15-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting oauth2client<2,>=1.5.2 (from google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached oauth2client-1.5.2.tar.gz
Collecting ply<4.0,>=3.8 (from google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached ply-3.9.tar.gz
Collecting pylru<2.0,>=1.0.9 (from google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached pylru-1.0.9.tar.gz
Collecting pyjwkest<=1.0.9,>=1.0.0 (from google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached pyjwkest-1.0.9.tar.gz
Collecting requests<3.0,>=2.10.0 (from google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached requests-2.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting strict-rfc3339<0.8,>=0.7 (from google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached strict-rfc3339-0.7.tar.gz
Collecting urllib3<2.0,>=1.16 (from google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached urllib3-1.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting httplib2>=0.8 (from google-apitools<0.5,>=0.4.15->google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached httplib2-0.9.2.zip
Collecting six>=1.9.0 (from google-apitools<0.5,>=0.4.15->google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools>=18.5 (from google-apitools<0.5,>=0.4.15->google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached setuptools-28.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.7 (from oauth2client<2,>=1.5.2->google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached pyasn1-0.1.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.0.5 (from oauth2client<2,>=1.5.2->google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting rsa>=3.1.4 (from oauth2client<2,>=1.5.2->google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached rsa-3.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycrypto>=2.6.1 (from pyjwkest<=1.0.9,>=1.0.0->google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz
Collecting future (from pyjwkest<=1.0.9,>=1.0.0->google-endpoints-api-management>=1.0.0b1->google-endpoints)
  Using cached future-0.15.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: cachetools, dogpile.cache, enum34, httplib2, six, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, rsa, oauth2client, setuptools, google-apitools, ply, pylru, pycrypto, requests, future, pyjwkest, strict-rfc3339, urllib3, google-endpoints-api-management, google-endpoints
  Running setup.py install for dogpile.cache ... done
  Running setup.py install for httplib2 ... done
  Running setup.py install for oauth2client ... done
  Running setup.py install for ply ... done
  Running setup.py install for pylru ... done
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/t1/2nf22s493sg5w56ytwzm1jvh0000gn/T/pip-build-2Vo85w/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/t1/2nf22s493sg5w56ytwzm1jvh0000gn/T/pip-G1Fh1N-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --home=/var/folders/t1/2nf22s493sg5w56ytwzm1jvh0000gn/T/tmpFgpq39:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto
    copying lib/Crypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto
    copying lib/Crypto/pct_warnings.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/hashalgo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/HMAC.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/MD2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/MD4.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/MD5.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/RIPEMD.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA224.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA256.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA384.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA512.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Hash
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/ARC2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/ARC4.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/Blowfish.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/CAST.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/DES.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/DES3.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/XOR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/_number_new.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/asn1.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/Counter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/number.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/py21compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/py3compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/randpool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/RFC1751.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/Util/winrandom.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Util
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Random
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Random
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Random
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/random.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Random
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaAccumulator.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaGenerator.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/SHAd256.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/fallback.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/nt.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/posix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/rng_base.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/st_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_AES.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_ARC2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_ARC4.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_Blowfish.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_CAST.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_DES.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_DES3.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_pkcs1_15.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_XOR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_HMAC.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_MD2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_MD4.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_MD5.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_RIPEMD.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA224.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA256.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA384.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA512.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_AllOrNothing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_chaffing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_KDF.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_rfc1751.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_DSA.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_ElGamal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_importKey.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_RSA.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/test_random.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/test_rpoolcompat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/test_SHAd256.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_fallback.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_generic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_nt.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_posix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_winrandom.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_asn1.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_Counter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_number.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_winrandom.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_pkcs1_15.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
    copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/AllOrNothing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/Chaffing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
    copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/KDF.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_DSA.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_RSA.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_slowmath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/DSA.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/ElGamal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/pubkey.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Signature
    copying lib/Crypto/Signature/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Signature
    copying lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_PSS.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Signature
    copying lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/Crypto/Signature
    running build_ext
    running build_configure
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... no
    configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/t1/2nf22s493sg5w56ytwzm1jvh0000gn/T/pip-build-2Vo85w/pycrypto':
    configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
    See `config.log' for more details
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/t1/2nf22s493sg5w56ytwzm1jvh0000gn/T/pip-build-2Vo85w/pycrypto/setup.py", line 456, in <module>
        core.setup(**kw)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 573, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/t1/2nf22s493sg5w56ytwzm1jvh0000gn/T/pip-build-2Vo85w/pycrypto/setup.py", line 251, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/t1/2nf22s493sg5w56ytwzm1jvh0000gn/T/pip-build-2Vo85w/pycrypto/setup.py", line 278, in run
        raise RuntimeError("autoconf error")
    RuntimeError: autoconf error

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/t1/2nf22s493sg5w56ytwzm1jvh0000gn/T/pip-build-2Vo85w/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/t1/2nf22s493sg5w56ytwzm1jvh0000gn/T/pip-G1Fh1N-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --home=/var/folders/t1/2nf22s493sg5w56ytwzm1jvh0000gn/T/tmpFgpq39" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/t1/2nf22s493sg5w56ytwzm1jvh0000gn/T/pip-build-2Vo85w/pycrypto/
```

For what it's worth, I am running on Python 2.7.10

Comment: What's in `config.log`?

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge here :) I cannot seem to find `config.log`. Do you have any idea where it might be? I searched my entire machine, and cannot find it.

Comment: No worries. I'm not sure; it's specific to your OS. Without looking further into that, are you sure that you have a C compiler installed? That's what the command says isn't working. You're also using OS X's built-in Python distribution, which has caused problems (at least for me) in the past. Have you thought about installing Python via Homebrew?