# Google App Engine configuring Endpoints API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints, gae-python27

I have a problem configuring Endpoints API. Any code i use, from my own, to google's examples on site fail with the same traceback

```
WARNING  2016-11-01 06:16:48,279 client.py:229] no scheduler thread, scheduler.run() will be invoked by report(...)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vladimir/projects/sb_fork/sb/lib/vendor/google/api/control/client.py", line 225, in start
self._thread.start()
File "/home/vladimir/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/background_thread/background_thread.py", line 108, in start
start_new_background_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
File "/home/vladimir/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/background_thread/background_thread.py", line 87, in start_new_background_thread
raise ERROR_MAP[error.application_error](error.error_detail)
FrontendsNotSupported
INFO     2016-11-01 06:16:48,280 client.py:327] created a scheduler to control flushing
INFO     2016-11-01 06:16:48,280 client.py:330] scheduling initial check and flush
INFO     2016-11-01 06:16:48,288 client.py:804] Refreshing access_token
/home/vladimir/projects/sb_fork/sb/lib/vendor/urllib3/contrib/appengine.py:113: AppEnginePlatformWarning: urllib3 is using URLFetch on Google App Engine sandbox instead of sockets. To use sockets directly instead of URLFetch see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contrib.html.
AppEnginePlatformWarning)
ERROR    2016-11-01 06:16:49,895 service_config.py:125] Fetching service config failed (status code 403)
ERROR    2016-11-01 06:16:49,896 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vladimir/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
File "/home/vladimir/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
File "/home/vladimir/sdk/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
obj = __import__(path[0])
File "/home/vladimir/projects/sb_fork/sb/main.py", line 27, in <module>
api_app = endpoints.api_server([SolarisAPI,], restricted=False)
File "/home/vladimir/projects/sb_fork/sb/lib/vendor/endpoints/apiserving.py", line 497, in api_server
controller)
File "/home/vladimir/projects/sb_fork/sb/lib/vendor/google/api/control/wsgi.py", line 77, in add_all
a_service = loader.load()
File "/home/vladimir/projects/sb_fork/sb/lib/vendor/google/api/control/service.py", line 110, in load
return self._load_func(**kw)
File "/home/vladimir/projects/sb_fork/sb/lib/vendor/google/api/config/service_config.py", line 78, in fetch_service_config
_log_and_raise(Exception, message_template.format(status_code))
File "/home/vladimir/projects/sb_fork/sb/lib/vendor/google/api/config/service_config.py", line 126, in _log_and_raise
raise exception_class(message)
Exception: Fetching service config failed (status code 403)
INFO     2016-11-01 06:16:49,913 module.py:788] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

My `app.yaml` is configured like the new Endpoints Migrating to 2.0 document states:

```
- url: /_ah/api/.*
  script: api.solaris.api_app
```

And `main.py` imports the API into the app:

```
api_app = endpoints.api_server([SolarisAPI,], restricted=False)
```

I use Google Cloud SDK with these versions:

```
Google Cloud SDK 132.0.0
app-engine-python 1.9.40
bq 2.0.24
bq-nix 2.0.24
core 2016.10.24
core-nix 2016.10.24
gcloud 
gsutil 4.22
gsutil-nix 4.22
```

Comment: I am having the same error with my endpoints project since upgrading to endpoints 4.0.0+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the "FrontendsNotSupported" you need to use a "B*" instance class.

The error "Exception: Fetching service config failed" should be gone if you follow the steps in https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/quickstart-frameworks-python. As already pointed out by Brad, the section "OpenAPI configuration" and the resulting environment variables are required to make the service configuration work.

Comment: I am not able to follow "you need to use a "B*" instance class."
Can you give more information on that?

Comment: @user362953 Your service instance in appengine has a class which specifies the class or resources(CPU, Memory) your application need/uses.  
`https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes`
you can find everything about that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried generating and uploading the OpenAPI configuration for the service? See the sections named ["Generating the OpenAPI configuration file"](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/quickstart-frameworks-python#generating_the_openapi_configuration_file) and ["Deploying the OpenAPI configuration file"](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/quickstart-frameworks-python#deploying_the_openapi_configuration_file) in the [python library documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/quickstart-frameworks-python).

Note that in step 2 of the generation process, you may need to prepend `python` to the command (e.g `python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_swagger_spec ...`), since the PyPi package doesn't preserve executable file permissions right now.

Comment: that is the missing step, i am having the same problems with the environment like in this issue, and i can't seem to resolve the appengine.ext 
[issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926853/error-running-endpointscfg-py-get-swagger-spec)

Comment: @Brad
I am seeing the same error even with the right `env_variables` in app.yaml.
Any idea why that could be the case?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310672/google-appengine-endpoints-error-fetching-service-config-failed-status-code-40 has more information.

Comment: I responded to the question, but copying what I said here -- the `gcloud service-management deploy` step probably didn't work as expected. I would try that again, making sure everything is configured correctly, and making sure there are no errors output in that command. Let me know if that works! :)

Comment: @BradFriedman: Thanks :)

I have related questions :)
I added API to my existing AppEngine WebApp. I only specified a handler "url: /_ah/spi/.*" and added the handler code.
I can see my endpoint through API Explorer and it's is working.
Among the steps in Quickstart referred in sebi's answer, I didn't  implement "Generating the OpenAPI configuration file" or "Deploying the OpenAPI configuration file".

This brings me to questions like: 
By omitting the OpenAPI steps, have I implemented only some steps for using Endpoints.
What is Endpoint Service? It seems I haven't used Service.