# How do I fix packaging issue when generating OpenAPI configuration file?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, virtualenv, google-cloud-endpoints

I am working through the Python Quickstart for Cloud Endpoints Frameworks on App Engine. I try to generate the OpenAPI configuration file by invoking the Endpoints Tool and get this error:

```
python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_swagger_spec main.EchoApi --hostname echo.endpoints.[YOUR-PROJECT-ID].cloud.goog


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 59, in <module>
import _endpointscfg_setup  # pylint: disable=unused-import
File "/Users/myName/lab/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/endpoints/_endpointscfg_setup.py", line 98, in <module>
_SetupPaths()
File "/Users/myName/lab/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/endpoints/_endpointscfg_setup.py", line 94, in _SetupPaths
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
ImportError: No module named appengine.ext
```

My understanding is that this is some kind of packaging issue? This is issue is discussed here but i am still stuck: [Error running endpointscfg.py get_swagger_spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926853/error-running-endpointscfg-py-get-swagger-spec?noredirect=1&lq=1). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: hey @dgmt i am stuck on the same problem that you replied to in the above linked question. Hoping you might be able to expand a bit more on how you resolved the issue. I have learnt how to create and activate a virtualenv directory to solve it but am unsure

Comment: *about how to use endpointscfg.py in it? Or maybe you know of some documentation that will help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with my system variable path. Specifically I added:

ENDPOINTS_GAE_SDK="path to google_appengine"