# Get ImportError: No module named control when following google cloud endpoint tutorial

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I am following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/quickstart-frameworks-python) on setting up cloud endpoints in python on googles app engine and keep on getting an import error

```
ImportError: No module named control
```

on the **Generating the OpenAPI configuration file** step when I input

```
python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_swagger_spec main.EchoApi --hostname echo-api.endpoints.projectid.cloud.goog
```

I followed these steps on a new account and still got this error. No idea what I am doing wrong/steps I am skipping.

here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 625, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 621, in main
    args.callback(args)
  File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 479, in _GenOpenApiSpecCallback
    application_path=args.application)
  File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 324, in _GenOpenApiSpec
    application_path=application_path)
  File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 181, in GenApiConfig
    module = __import__(module_name, fromlist=base_service_class_name)
  File "/home/hairyhenry/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    import endpoints
  File "/home/hairyhenry/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/endpoints/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from apiserving import *
  File "/home/hairyhenry/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard/endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo/lib/endpoints/apiserving.py", line 74, in <module>
    from google.api.control import client as control_client
ImportError: No module named control
```

any insight would be fabulous

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using 2.0.0, but using the b2 release instead worked for me.
Remove the `lib` folder and run:

`pip install -t lib google-endpoints==2.0.0b2`

Using this version will generate a file called `echo-v1_swagger.json` instead of `echov1openapi.json` as stated in the documentation, so you'll have to run the following to deploy the config file instead:

`gcloud service-management deploy echo-v1_swagger.json`

Comment: This does not generate the echo-v1_swagger.json file for me. Am I looking at the wrong place?

Comment: @haopei: you still have to run the relevant `python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_swagger_spec ...` command after installing the b2 version.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of a library conflict between your environment and the app. This is what [this page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/853) indicates, and the advice at the end worked for me:

> I would recommend activating an empty virtualenv before running endpointscfg.py so that your system packages don't cause issues.

I did this with:

```
mkdir /tmp/ve
virtualenv /tmp/ve
/tmp/ve/bin/python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the same issue reported as [#35901199](https://issuetracker.google.com/35901199) at the issue tracker, and it was marked as the intended behavior since the [Control API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/servicecontrol/v1) is a part of the [Google API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/) and you can run the command 'pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client' to install it, which should solve the 'No module' errors. That said, we should also report this issue at the [issue tracker here](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-python/issues/54).